# C# Making other window transparent

Tags: c#, transparency

Is it possible to change opacity on another window ( that's not a part of the program ) in C#??

Answer (score 1):

You must use Win32API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx

Comment: What should I do after FindWindow() ?